# How to add caching to a streamed image in Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side

Having followed [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-6.0#stream-image-data) to streaming images from somewhere to Blazor, I have this component and javascript code:

Javascript file for changing the content of an img tag:

```
window.setImage = async (imageElementId, imageStream) => {
    const arrayBuffer = await imageStream.arrayBuffer();
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const image = document.getElementById(imageElementId);
    image.onload = () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
    image.src = url;
}
```

And the component:

```
<img id="@ImageName" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private ImageStreamService _imageStreamService { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var imageResult = await _imageStreamService.GetAnImageStream(ImageName);
        using var dotnetImageStream = new DotNetStreamReference(imageResult.Stream);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setImage", ImageName, dotnetImageStream);

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

This works great, the image is shown where I type `<MyImageComponent ImageName="foo" />`. However, I would like to cache these images on the client's browser instead of retrieving them from a server every time for obvious reasons. However, I can't find any existing code on how to do this. My first guess is that I have to add headers in the JavaScript file to add caching headers, but I can't find the right way to do this. Also, the image URL generated appears to be a different GUID every time I hit F5, which makes caching difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching simply isn't possible when following Microsoft's own example in this case. The URL generated by `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` can not be altered in any way. So to enable caching, you need a URL that doesn't change. The best you can do is add a controller to the solution that returns the image, and setting caching attributes on that. In `Startup.cs`, add update your `app.UseEndpoints` call to this:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
```

Then add a controller as normal:

```
    [HttpGet("{imageName}")]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 3600, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage(string imageName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var imageStream = await GetImageAsStream(imageName, cancellationToken);
        return Ok(new FileStreamResult(imageStream, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

Then you can just add the ResponseCache attribute in the controller, and use `img` tags with the URL to this endpoint. Or you can create a component that creates an `img` element with whatever parameters you want.

Adding controllers isn't the Blazor way of thinking, but if I have to choose between sticking to the Blazor architecture as close as possible, or being able to cache images client-side, it's an easy choice. Alternatively, you can decouple your image endpoint to an external system (like a CMS).